# How can I call a function defined in a form from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, interface

I have 2 forms and I want to call a function of `Form1` defined in an interface from `Form2`. I tried using delegates and events. Is there a better way of doing this?

## Form1

```
namespace atszodidb
{
    public partial  class Form1 : Form
    {

    }
}

interface db
{
    void func(string param);
}

class db_veiksmai : db // veiksmai = actions
{

    public db_veiksmai()
    {

    }

    public  void func(string param)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(param);
    }
}
```

## Form2

```
namespace atszodidb
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        void function()
        {

        }
    {
}
```

How to call `void func(string param)` from function  `void function()`? I tried to do this with a delegate:

## Program.cs

```
public static class Data
{
    public delegate void MyEvent(string data);
    public static MyEvent EventHandler;
}
```

and in `Form2`

```
Data.EventHandler("lalalal");
```

However, I don't know where to write `Data.EventHandler = new Data.MyEvent(func);`. I tried in the constructor of `class db_veiksmai`, but it's a bad solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: See, In Form1 i have function which work with database (insert, delete), in Form2 i have data which I must send to FORM1 and insert to dataase, now understand me ?

Comment: but you mean the form1 file or class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of a class in order to call an instance method. So:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    void function()
    {
        db_veiksmai mydb = new db_veiksmai();
        mydb.func("some parameter");
    }
}
```

Or have your Form2 take the interface as a constructor dependency:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly db _mydb;
    public Form2(db mydb)
    {
        _mydb = mydb;
    }

    void function()
    {
        _mydb.func("some parameter");
    }
}
```

and now it will be the responsibility of the consumer of Form2 to pass a specific implementation of `db` when constructing `Form2`.

Remark: in .NET as a convention interface names start with `I`, and `db` is a very poor name for an interface.

Comment: I can't use like this because is interface

Comment: @user1069874, of course that you can. In the first case you are working directly with a concrete implementation (`db_veiksmai`) whereas in the second example it is the responsibility of the caller of Form2 to provide a specific implementation and thus decoupling the code in Form2 from a specific implementation.

Comment: Ok thanks for answer, and 1 more question use of delegate and events is very bad solution form this problem ?

Comment: @user1069874, I don't know. It will depend on your exact scenario and the specific problem you are trying to solve.